# Cytoscape.js with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, cytoscape.js

I want to use leaflet as Map library and use Cytoscape.js to display nodes as overlay. Also node locations are updated with zoom in and zoom out. What are the challenges on the way. Any suggestions? 
I have list can anyone support :
Use canvas element as overlay on leaflet.
how to translate geo location to canvas location
relocating nodes on zoom in  and zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the challenges on the way?

A lot. You'll have to be more specific when asking.

> Use canvas element as overlay on leaflet.

See the documentation for `L.Canvas` (and its source code if you want to implement something similar).

> how to translate geo location to canvas location relocating nodes on zoom in and zoom out.

See the `L.Map.LatLngToContainerPoint()` method. Zoom animations are handled via CSS and screen coordinates of map layers are not recalculated during zoom animation frames.